# T-SQL XML do not return element if no child elements

Tags: t-sql

I do not want to return a Xml element if no child elements exists:

```
SELECT 
(
        SELECT
                'nl' AS [@Language]
                ,'test' AS [@Value]
        WHERE 1=0
        FOR XML PATH('Translation'), ROOT('Translations'), TYPE
)
FOR XML RAW('IngredientStatement'), TYPE
```

In this case `<IngredientStatement />` is returned.

Comment: What do you want to return?

Comment: Nothing, NULL or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to separate the inner select into a common table expression:

```
;WITH InnerXmlCte AS
(
    SELECT 
    (
            SELECT
                    'nl' AS [@Language]
                    ,'test' AS [@Value]
            WHERE 1=0
            FOR XML PATH('Translation'),  TYPE
    ) As Translations
)

SELECT Translations
FROM InnerXmlCte
WHERE Translations IS NOT NULL
FOR XML RAW('IngredientStatement'), TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach was to add an `XQuery`, filtering for `<IngredientStatement>` with any content:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT 
    (
            SELECT
                    'nl' AS [@Language]
                    ,'test' AS [@Value]
            WHERE 1=0
            FOR XML PATH('Translation'), ROOT('Translations'), TYPE
    )
    FOR XML RAW('IngredientStatement'), TYPE
).query('/IngredientStatement[*]')
```